# How to define complexity of operations with QT containers?

Tags: c++, qt

Starting to dig into QT programming and stuck into the problem, that I can't really understand how their containers really work under the hood. For example, I would like (and probably should) to use `QByteArray` to work with data from `QTcpSocket`, but I'm afraid of using things that I don't really understand (performance-wise). For `std::` containers there is `cppreference.com` where I can find complexity and probable realization of every operation, but QT documentation not providing such of information. So, the question is: where to find complete information about QT containers?

Comment: There is a very small table [there](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/containers.html#algorithmic-complexity).

Comment: Also mind that `QByteArray` is not a container. It's just an object wrapping some kind of `const char*` under the hood, the same way an `std::string` just wraps a C-style string - with some fancy templating for sure but still just a wrapper.

Comment: @NicoJ. yes, understand that, but how can I be sure, that, for example, when I do `remove` from the start of `QByteArray`, there is no moving all the data but just changing pointer of the start?